# Time series model without ARMA component and with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, arima, ardl, armax

I am trying to know what is the most simple model for time series data, with exogenous variables. What is the most simple framework I can use ? Is it possible to build a model more simple than ARIMAX, ECM, VARX or ARDL, and, specifically, a model without any AR or MA component ?

I imagine something just as simple as :

$$Y_{t} = \alpha_{1}X_{1,t} + \alpha_{2}X_{2,t} + u_{t}$$

with most probably some time-series-specific properties (all series stationary, stationary residual, etc.).

Is it possible ?

Sorry if I talk complete non-sense, but I can’t wrap my head around an AR or a MA component being mandatory while I’m interested by which *exogenous* variable is useful to predict $Y_t$.

Comment: Hi: yes. what you have is fine ( no ARIMA terms necessary ) but three things to consider: 1) should the X's be lagged by one time unit ? or do they really occur so that the current X's influence the current $Y$ ?  2) You may want to add a lagged dependent variable to the RHS so say $\alpha_0  Y_{t-1}$. If you choose not to, then your assumption is that any effects due to $X_{i}$ are instantaneous and don't carry over to future time periods. 3) Think about the error term being independent ? Does that seems reasonable for your model ?

Comment: @mlofton, your comment answers the question. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: okay. I'll cut and paste. good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have is fine ( no ARIMA terms necessary ) but three things to consider:

1. should the X's be lagged by one time unit ? or do they really occur so that the current X's influence the current  ?
2. You may want to add a lagged dependent variable to the RHS so say $\alpha _{t-1}$. If you choose not to, then your assumption is that any effects due to  are instantaneous and don't carry over to future time periods.
3. Think about the error term being independent ? Does that seems reasonable for your model ?

#===============================================================
#12-05-2023
#===============================================================

ADDENDUM: To clarify the third point. Take a simple AR(1).

$y_t = \rho y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $

Even though $\epsilon_t$ is independent, if we write the model
using the lagged operator, we end up with:

$y_t = \sum_{i=0}^{t} \rho^{i} \epsilon_{t-i}$

So each $y_t$ has all the previous $\epsilon_t$ contained in it
so the $y_t$ are not independent, even though $\epsilon_t$ is independent. So, the point is that the error term can matter in
that, even when it looks independent, it has dependency
implications that may not be obvious.

Comment: Hi mlofton, thank you for your detailed answer. I have market it as solving the question. I will definitely consider option 1) as I am not positive yet about whether the effect of X on Y will be contemporary or not. Option 2) is probably what I need, i.e. I will probably include an AR term anyway. I have a concrete model to build but my question was also kind of a theoretical, i.e. I wanted to understand if the existence of such model with minimal requirements was even theoretically possible.

Comment: I definitely lack some knowledge or understanding for your point 3). I have always assumed that dependant errors (which, as far as I know, is equivalent to autocorrelated errors) will make problems for the model. Therefore, I never wonder if independent errors make sense, I just assume that's just the way it should be. I always assume that independance/no auto-correlation is needed.  Can you tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: Hi Johannes: I've been at this stuff a while so no problem explaining. I added some material at the bottom of my answer. I recommend Andrew Harvey's text:  "the econometric analysis of time series" in order to see how the independent-dependency of error terms can be quite subtle. He writes in a way that can be difficult at first reading ( very terse ) but, if you read him a few times, you can eventually see that there is a lot of gold in what he says. This is actually true of all his books but check out that one first.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the additional elements on your response ! I will give a try to this textbook, to see if I can understand this point a little better. If I'm not too busy I will try to comment further this thread in order to give solution to whoever is intersted.

Comment: Hi: it's more of a time-series book and, not easy, especially because it's your first introduction to Harvey's style. But, like I said, Harvey's books are deceiving. They are not easy to read but you read them a couple  of times ( or more ), let them sink in and, eventually, you realize that there is a lot of unique info in his writings.

Comment: Also, google for, "koyck distributed lag". that's an example of a non-arima time series model that captures, a lagged effect, similar to I was talking about in one of my comments.

Comment: That's noted, thanks for the tip. I have already read a bit of the textbook (free extracts) and it seems I've simply confused errors, disturbances and residuals. AFAIU, disturbances and errors are the same. When modeled through AR(p) and MA(q) process, they have self-dependancy over time. If on contrary they're independant, I can only assume AR/MA are out of the equation (hence your question 3 ?). As for residuals, my assumption that "residuals must always be not auto-correlated" seems wrong. The textbook says if disturbances are correlated, residuals will be (albeit inverse is not true).

Comment: Hi: Try to through that textbook and also think what you're trying to capture. Definitely arima is just one way to model things and no reason to get hung up on it. Sometimes a lagged variable along with regressor(s) can work just as well. I hope it helps.

Comment: Well, it's increasingly complex. The more I discover, the more I have doubts. 1) I suppose errors would be independant. $Y_t$ would be losses on clients' loans, and $X_t$ are some macroeconomics. AR(p) would probably be useful for better predicting my model, and so I can see dependance arising from the AR term, as you mentioned in your Dec,12 addendum. But for errors themselves, I don't see why they would be dependant.

Comment: 2) in a broader perspective, I am getting lost about the proper framework to look for. The more I read, the more confused I am. Initially I thought that the model you suggested I could use was in fact an ARDL. But now I have learnt that there also exist something called ARX. Now how to differentiate (and choose) between ARDL and ARX ? Are these not both time-series with auto-regressive component AND exogenous variables that may be, or may be not, be lagged ? (should I create a separate question on this one ?)

Comment: The errors can be independent. I just thought that there might be a reason that they werent. As far as ARX and ARDL, they are close to the same thing. The ARDL has better coverage in the literature so I would use that, with a lagged dependent variable and the two X's you originally referred to. No need to get confused about the various acronyms. Plot the variables Y versus X1 and also Y versus X2 and see how they look.

Comment: Hi mlofton. Thanks a lot for your response ! I will try that.